# Does the equation $x = a\sin^2\omega t$ represent a simple harmonic motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I've asked this question due a doubt in the following question.

> The displacement of a particle along the $x$-axis is given by $x = a\sin^2\omega t$. The motion of the particle corresponds to
>
> (1) simple harmonic motion of frequency $\omega/\pi$
> (2) simple harmonic motion of frequency $3\omega/2\pi$
> (3) non simple harmonic motion
> (4) simple harmonic motion of frequency $\omega/2\pi$

According to various sources which I've referred the answer is contradictory.

(a) The answer given is option (3). This is is accordance to the following excerpt of the NCERT textbook.

> $$\sin^2\omega t=\frac12-\frac12\cos2\omega t$$
> The function is periodic having a period $T=\pi/\omega$. It also represents a harmonic motion with the point of equilibrium occuring at $\frac12$ instead of zero.

(b) But according to the book *Concepts of Physics* by HC Verma, and various others found on the internet, simple harmonic motion is defined as the one in which $F = -kx$ and sine function is one of its solutions.

If the equation is rearranged, as shown in the book, should it be considered as simple harmonic motion with equilibrium position at $+1/2$ unit and angular frequency of $2\omega$?

What is the exact difference between harmonic motion and simple harmonic motion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322609/can-a-periodic-motion-whose-displacement-is-given-by-x-sin2-omega-t-be-c?rq=1

Comment: Regardless of the answer, this is a bad question because it depends on the precise definition of simple harmonic motion, and no actual physicist cares about that. The motion is harmonic around $x=1/2$, who cares what you call it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(a) I think that *harmonic motion* is just an abbreviation for *simple harmonic motion*. It doesn't mean another sort of motion. [Compare *proportional*, which means just the same as *directly proportional*!]

(b) $x=A \sin^2\omega t$ is an interesting 'borderline case'. Either answer: not SHM or SHM of frequency $2\omega$ could be defended.

In favour of **not SHM** is that $x=A \sin^2\omega t$ does not satisfy the differential equation $\ddot x=-\omega^2 x$, but the slightly different equation $\ddot x=a_0-\omega'^2 x$ in which $a_0$ is a constant and $\omega'=2\omega$.

In favour of **SHM of frequency $2\omega$** is that, as shown using your quoted trigonometric identity, $x=A \sin^2\omega t$ gives a displacement time graph that is a perfect sinusoid, albeit displaced vertically by a fixed amount.

My view is in favour of $x=A \sin^2\omega t$ being SHM of frequency $2\omega$. I would prefer textbooks to define SHM as motion in which the displacement–time graph is a sinusoid (however shifted with respect to either axis), rather than as motion obeying $\ddot x=-\omega^2 x$. But that's just *my* view.

Postscript: I agree entirely with Javier's comment on the question that the student was set.